# python regex unexpected match groups

Tags: python, regex-group, python-re

I am trying to find all occurrences of either `"_"+digit` or `"^"+digit`, using the regex `((_\^)[1-9])`

The groups I'd expect back eg for `"X_2ZZZY^5"` would be `[('_2'), ('^5')]` but instead I am getting `[('_2', '_'), ('^5', '^')]`

Is my regex incorrect?  Or is my expectation of what gets returned incorrect?

Many thanks

** my original re used `(_|\^)` this was incorrect, and should have been `(_\^)` -- question has been amended accordingly

Comment: You have two sets of parenthesis, so you'll get two groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 groups in your regex - so you're getting 2 groups. And you need to match atleast 1 number that follows.

try this:

```
([_\^][1-9]+)
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/pgxUmc/1)

Answer (score 2):

Demand at least 1 digit (1-9) following the special characters `_` or `^`, placed inside a single capture group:

```
import re

text = "X_2ZZZY^5"
pattern = r"([_\^][1-9]{1,})"
regex = re.compile(pattern)
res = re.findall(regex, text)
print(res)
```

Returning:

```
['_2', '^5']
```